# How to select the values from the results of a previous query, to insert said values in a WHERE clause for a subsequent query?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using Toad for Oracle.

I wrote this query to select some `BATCH_ID`s from a table called `PM_BATCH_ST`:

```
SELECT BATCH_ID
FROM PM_BATCH_ST
WHERE COLUMN_DATA1 IS NULL
```

I get these results:

| BATCH_ID |
| --- |
| 1000574893 |
| 1000384676 |
| 1000377654 |

There is another table called `LG_EBR_ACTION_LIST`, and I'd like to query it for `RECIPE_ID`s where the `BATCH_ID` is any of the batch IDs from the results of the previous query.

I understand, I could just type the `BATCH_ID`s manually in the `WHERE` clause. But is there any way to insert these values in the `WHERE` clause by referring to the `BATCH_ID`s column that resulted from the query of the `PM_BATCH_ST` table?

Something like:

```
SELECT RECIPE_ID
FROM LG_EBR_ACTION_LIST
WHERE BATCH_ID = 'the Batch IDs from my Query of the PM_BATCH_ST Table when COLUMN_DATA1 in that Table is Null'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT RECIPE_ID
FROM LG_EBR_ACTION_LIST
WHERE BATCH_ID IN (
    SELECT BATCH_ID
    FROM PM_BATCH_ST
    WHERE COLUMN_DATA1 IS NULL
);
```

Comment: Thank You.
I tried that but I received the following error message:
ORA-00936: missing expression

Found 'IN': Expecting: ( + - CASE CONNECT_BY_ROOT decimal-number FALSE FINAL float host-identifier identifier integer NEW NULL PRIOR QUALIFY RUNNING SHARE_OF SQL string TRUE -or- ALL ANY SOME